# What is the advantage to declaring objects in fields?

Tags: java, object, field

How is typing:

```
public class Example  
{  
    private Cat whiskers;  

    public void makeCat()  
    {  
        whiskers = new Cat();  
    }  
}
```

different than:

```
public class Example  
{  
    public void makeCat()  
    {  
        Cat whiskers = new Cat();  
    }  
}
```

it seems that the first example is more work because you can now only create Cat objects named whiskers from it. Why declare it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first you are declaring a private variable that may be used within the same instance by other methods (or properties). However, in your second example you are just declaring a variable with a local scope, in other words, this variable will only be visible within `makeCat()`.

Comment: hmmmm... you should be careful with your wording. Consider a method `void doSomething(Cat cat) {...`, which could use the Cat instance in example #2 if it was passed to it

Comment: but if it's a field, the name of it is already declared so I cant make any more Cat objects(with that field) that aren't called whiskers right?

Comment: @Bohemian good point, still in scope of makeCat() though, right?

Comment: @CollinDutter, like you said that field name `whiskers` is already taken at the class level. However, you can still declare a local variable within your methods called `whiskers` too. In this case you will distinguish the class-level variable with the keyword `this`.

Comment: Got it. And what exactly can I do with the field whiskers? Can I access it from another class like any other field variable\? (assuming i've created an Example object or made whiskers static).

Comment: Your `Example` class can do anything with it. However, other classes cannot access it directly. This is called encapsulation, this article will explain this better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a good book about the basics of Object Oriented Programming.

In the first case you are declaring a "private member variable". This is now a part of the class and can be used in other member functions or even from outside.

In the second case you are declaring a "local variable". This is a variable that is valid only within the function in which it is defined, and it is used for calculations within the function only. It cannot be accessed from outside/from other functions of the class.

Answer (score 0):

An Object is declared in the field of the another object when first object is the part of the 
second object. 
Example-:

```
class Product
  {
    int productId;
    ProductDetail detail;
  }

class ProductDetail
   {
     string brand;
     int price;
     string description;
   }
```

In the above example, one object of product class corresponds to the one Product and each product has some details.So whenever Product class object is created ProductDetail class object is created by the JVM.

In case of your first scenario, When Example class object is created anywhere then Cat class object is created by the JVM.
In case of second scenario, It is just a local variable in that method. And there is no Cat Object while creating the Example class object.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the first example uses a *field* (a.k.a. "instance variable "), which *other* methods can also reference (ie "use") it without it being passed to the method.

The second example is a local variable - it can only be used within that method (or other methods if *passed* to them).